# Why does the midpoint method have error $O(h^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In solving an ode

$$ y'(t) = f(t, y(t)), \quad y(t_0) = y_0 $$

the [midpoint method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method) estimates

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + hf\left(t_n+\frac{h}{2},y_n+\frac{h}{2}f(t_n, y_n)\right)$$

But why is the error $O(h^2)$? The estimate for Euler's method is straightforward since it's just the Taylor approximation, but here it doesn't look like a Taylor approximation.

Comment: "Because of the time symmetry of the implicit method, all terms of even degree in $h$ of the local error cancel, so that the local error is automatically of order $O(h^3)$", and [Notes on truncation error](http://livetoad.org/Courses/Documents/03e0/Notes/truncation_error.pdf)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin do you mind explaining that in some more detail? I don't really get it.

Comment: I don't follow this much, have just read it on your wiki link, about the local truncation error is being $O(h^3)$. The pdf I linked is more easy for me to follow, it gives "local $O(h^{m+1}) \rightarrow$ global $O(h^m)$"

Comment: You might want to look at [the discussion by Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner](http://books.google.com/books?id=cfZDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA216).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: The symmetry argument only applies to the implicit midpoint method. In question however is the explicit method. The error term depends on the error formula used. Often it is $$\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}-\Phi_f(t,x(t),h)=O(h^p)$$ to be compatible with the order of the global error.

Answer (score 4):

Using 
$$
Φ_f(t,y,h)=f\Bigl(t+\tfrac12h, y+\tfrac12 h·f(t,y)\Bigr)
$$
and inserting an exact solution of $y'=f(t,y)$ with $y(t_n)=y_n$ one gets
\begin{align}
\frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}h=
Φ_f(t_n,y(t_n),h)&=f\Bigl(t_n+\tfrac12h, y(t_n)+\tfrac12 h·y'(t_n)\Bigr)
\\ \\
&=f\Bigl(t_n+\tfrac12h, y\bigl(t_n+\tfrac12 h\bigr)+O(h^2)\Bigr)
\\ \\
&=f\Bigl(t_n+\tfrac12h, y\bigl(t_n+\tfrac12 h\bigr)\Bigr)+O(h^2)
\\ \\
&=y'\bigl(t_n+\tfrac12 h\bigr)+O(h^2)
\\ \\
&=\frac{y(t_n+h)-y(t_n)}{h}+O(h^2)
\end{align}
which is not that much more complicated than the similar computation for Eulers method.

Comment: Could you explain the last inequality? This is not immediately evident.

Comment: That is using the central difference quotient centered at $t+\frac12h$ with step $\frac12h$.

Comment: This incurs an additional $O(h^2)$, right?

Comment: Yes. The remainders are usually not the same from step to step, only in the same class.